# Create vue Permission denied

Tags: linux, vue.js, ubuntu

I'm trying to install vue app using this command  "npm init vue@latest",

But the following error occurred with me, any help :(

Note : I tried many solutions like : chmod -R 755 .npm and sudo chown -R mostafa .npm but nothing changes [image]

Comment: I recommend switching to a Node version manager (`nvm`) that handles these permission issues automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install vue on your machine you must first have installed nodejs ( package manager node package manager ) **to which the acronym npm refers**, I leave you the linux commands under :

install :

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

shows the installed version of nodejs :

```
node -v
```

After installing nodejs try relaunching the command to install vue

if you have already installed them try with this :
add write permissions to the study folder , and not to the mostafa folder , linux only assigns permissions to the folder in the chmod command and not subfolders, try these commands :

```
cd home/mostafa/Dowloads

sudo chmod ugo+w study
```

Comment: nodejs is already the newest version (10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1).

version : v16.14.0

Comment: for create a new project try with this command : vue create hello-world .
here there is link of the documentation : ( https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html )

Comment: vue --version what answer do you give ? 
try to update vue , ( mine is @vue/cli 4.5.15)  , if you can’t find it, install vue ,  with this command : npm install -g @vue/cli

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try using the vue-cli like this:

`npm install -g @vue/cli && vue create hello-world`

If this wouldn't work then I'd suggest to reinstall node/npm

You should probably also make a clean installation of these tools so that you don't need to run such things as administrator

Comment: `@vue/cli` is deprecated for `create-vue`.

Comment: `vue-cli` is deprecated `@vue/cli` is not, it doesn't state anywhere in the docs that it would be deprecated https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

Comment: The site hasn't yet been updated, but the [`@vue/cli` GitHub page has](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli#status): `Vue CLI is now in maintenance mode. For new Vue 3 projects, please use create-vue to scaffold Vite-based projects.`. The [official docs also state the same message](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#project-scaffolding).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have installed Nodejs, vue and create-vue.

```bash
sudo apt install nodejs
npm install vue@latest
npm install create-vue@latest
```

Now you can run the command to start the new project with Vue.

```bash
npm init vue@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you not being blocked by SELinux directives?
Try running the same command using your least privileged user (normal user).

And please avoid using the root user for everyday tasks.